# Finding the path with the minimum weight given a function

Tags: algorithm

I'm given an undirected graph `G = (V, E)` , a vertex `s` in `V`, and a function `w:E->{0,1}`. Given any `v` in `V`, I need to return the weight of a path (weight of a path = sum of the wight of the edges of the path) with the minimum weight from `s` to `v` in `O(|V| + |E|)` time.
.

This might sound like a homework question I'm too lazy to solve (I get these responses from time to time), but I've been trying REALLY hard to solve this problem, and I would highly appreciate any help or direction you might have for me.

Comment: There is a linear algorithm by M. Thorup but I cannot find its (non paying) description...

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by analogue of BFS algo, but with deque (D) instead of queue. Algo uses list of flags "is marked" for each vertex, initialized to false. Distances to s will appear, so you can store them or use "on the fly".

D will store pairs (vertex, distance_label).

Algo starts:

D is initialized by (s, 0).

On each iteration extract front (head) vertex from D (vertex v) with distance label d.

If v has already marked as reached, skip to next iteration.

Otherwise, mark v as reached. Now d is the correct distance between s and v. For each its unreached neighbour (vertex w) update it's distance label (d_w=d+dist(v,w)) and put pair(w, d_w) to head of D if dist(v,w)=0 or put it to tail, otherwise.

Algo ends.

You can store distances to all vertices when you will mark them as reached. All unreached vertices have infinity distance, probably.

Working time is O(|V|+|E|) since you process each vertex and each edge (in connected component with s) exactly once.

The correctness of algo can be proved by induction by distance to s.